# Adding file to JSON using Blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

I've working on the frontend for a new type of survey question that allows users to upload an image file. Given that jQuery doesn't natively support file uploading, I'm trying to use the [jQuery File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

I'm having trouble writing a custom method for getting the file via the plugin and inserting it into our standard json format. Here's how we would do it:

```
var url = "sendAnswer.json";
var questionId = 11; //This is set elsewhere
var fileValue = // Need to get the image file here
$.post(url,{
 "data[Answer][question_id]": questionId,
 "data[Answer][value]" : fileValue
});
```

How can I properly set the options in fileupload to match what I need to send? Basically I need to get the upload file into the data array. By default, I believe it's handled separately by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make an object with the correct formatting first and then pass that object:

```
var url = "sendAnswer.json";
var questionId = 11; //This is set elsewhere
var fileValue = // Need to get the image file here
dataObj = {"Answer": {"question_id": questionId, "value": fileValue}};
$.post(url,{
"data": dataObj
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but my main question is how to get the image file handled by the plugin to be set as an object that I can pass in the array. In this case, set it as `var fileValue`

Comment: There's a ton of documentation and demos on the git readme files: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to the question I asked way back in case someone is trying to do something similar. You can grab the image details via data.files on callbacks (such as "add").

```
var theUrl = 'url here';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: theUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        // Can do things with the data here, "files" has details about the image
        console.log(data.files);
})
```